# Sidebar not appearing on the right in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, genesis

I am having problems with my sidebar not appearing on the right of the shop page. I have tried editing the file "archive-product.php" but still can't seem to sort this out. The site link is http://www.graceplenty.com/. The code in my file is the following :

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post      type archive.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );?>


    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             *
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' =>     woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>


<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */

    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

?>


    <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>



<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Comment: It does display for me, but it's at the bottom of the page

Comment: You tried to figure it out @Howli

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following style to your css should move the sidebar to the right hand side of the screen:

```
div#container 
{
    width: 67%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Will this not affect my Genesis Theme? Should I put this style in the Woocommerce style.css

Comment: Putting it in the normal css should be okay. It shouldn't effect the Genesis Theme, if it does then try putting it only in the woocommerce style.css

Comment: @WoocommerceLover did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', '_woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'no_title' );
function no_title(){
    return false;
}
function _woocommerce_output_content_wrapper(){
    echo '<div class="content"><div class="entry-content">';
    genesis_do_breadcrumbs();
    echo '<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">';
    woocommerce_page_title();
    echo '</h1>';
}
```